# Working on WAMP but not on LAMP

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#voiceMail").click(function(){
if(realStatus == 'Registered.')
{
     var username=window.frames["iframeIphone"].username.value;//--Here is some problem i guess.

      $(".display").load("Images/Working.gif"); // for loading delay
      $(".display").load("AMI/AMI.php",{'info[]':[username]}); // The main file to be loaded. 
}     
  });
});
</script>
</head>
```

I am using Jquery Ajax and my task of to load AMI.php when i click in VoiceMail button. This code works well if i run it with WAMP server on windows but i dont work when i put this code in to LAMP server of linux.

Comment: Is the javascript coming from the LAMP server?  What part isn't working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the backslash in your first `.load()` call. You **never** want backslashes in hardcoded paths; no matter which OS you are using. Replace it with a slash instead:

```
$(".display").load("Images/Working.gif"); // for loading delay
```

Besides that, `.load()` is not really meant to be used to display images but rather to load HTML into an element.

Comment: Ops..! Thanks it was my mistake.
But what about the other one ?

Answer (score 1):

Many filesystems commonly used on Linux are case-sensitive, whereas most filesystems commonly used on Windows are not. Check the case of your paths.